# Convert 16:9 video to 9:16 with letterbox in Handbrake

Tags: resolution, video-conversion, handbrake

I have a video in 16:9 format that I will be uploading to Instagram live via onestream.live that is getting cropped by Instagram because it's in horizontal format, not vertical.

How can I use handbrake to convert the 16:9 format to the correct 9:16 format for Instagram?

I would like to have black letterbox strips on the top and bottom of the video.

Here are the dimensions for the source video:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close and Reopen Handbrake and under 'Dimensions' set your 'Resolution & Scaling' to the opposite numbers from your current video. Now 'Open Source' the video. This should give you a cleaner slate to start with for making the presets that you need.

720 x 480 set 'Scaled Size' and/maybe 'Max Size' to 480 x 720
Borders to Width (Pillarbox)

You'll have to experiment with 'Optimal Size' and 'Allow Upscaling' but you should see a different Aspect Ratio for Final Dimension (4.5:3)

Do short amount of time so you can quickly figure out what works. Upload might be the best way to know if setting are working for Instagram. Save 'New Preset' once you get it scaled correctly.

Let us know if this worked or got you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I'm accepting the answer above for pointing me in the exact right direction, thank you!

For others, here's what worked:

[image]